# Why is the moment of inertia about the $x$-axis used in deflection?

Tags: moment-of-inertia, continuum-mechanics

I am following along [this page](http://www.clag.org.uk/beam.html) for an experiment on the Young's Modulus of a beam by deflection, and I don't understand why they use the rotational inertia about the $x$ axis of the beam: 
$$I = \frac{bh^3}{12}.$$

I have found that this comes from:

$$
I_x = \iint_R z^2dA = \int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}}\int_{-\frac{b}{2}}^{\frac{b}{2}} z^2dxdz = b\int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}} z^2dz = \frac{bh^3}{12}.
$$

Since we're deflecting the beam down (along the z axis), wouldn't it make sense to use the z inertia instead?

Comment: It's difficult to know exactly what you mean because neither you nor your link ever define a coordinate system. But it doesn't matter whether you call it the moment of inertia "about the $x$ axis" or the moment of inertia "for $z$-direction beam deflections". (Presumably then the beam points in the $y$ direction?) It's the same equation. The point is that deflection in a certain direction should be penalized much more if the beam cross section extends more in that direction. That's what the $h^3$ term achieves (corresponding to the cross section height, or the dimension in the $z$ direction).

Comment: That is the area moment of inertia, which is different from the rotational moment of inertia. The rotational inertia of a plate of dimensions $h$ and $b$ with mass $m$ is $\frac{m}{12}(b^2 + h^2)$ about an axis through the center.

Comment: $I_x$  is _not rotational inertia_. It is [area moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area) of the section.

Comment: Mr. Russ Elliott (the author of the article) is responsible for propagating a common confusion in this topic. His terminology of "moment of inertia" instead of "area moment" does not help to clarify the differences:
$$\begin{array}{r|ccl}
\text{Term} & \text{Definition} & \text{Units} & \text{Notes}\\
\hline \text{Moment of Inertia} & I_{xx}=\iiint\left(y^{2}+z^{2}\right){\rm d}m & {\rm kg\,m^{2}} & \text{used in dynamics with rotations}\\
\text{Area Moment} & I_{xx}=\iint y^{2}{\rm d}A & {\rm m^{4}} & \text{used in flexible beams }
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The short answer:

Bending is due to internal moments (torques) that cause movement along a plane. On this case bending is along the *yz* plane, and therefore the moment responsible has to be along the *x* axis. You can view bending as kind of rotation, whose axis is perpendicular to the plane of movement.

### The long answer:

Consider a diagram of the situation

[image: diagram]

The point of the area moment $I_x$ is to related the applied moment $M_x = \ell \, F_z$ to the *slope* $K$ of stress field on the cross section. This slope is used to find stress value at each height $z$ along the cross section $$ \sigma_y(z) = K\,z $$

This slope depends on two things. One is the applied moment $M_x$ and the other is the shape of the cross section. The shape contribution is called the *area moment* and it is used as follows

$$ \begin{aligned} K & = \frac{M_x}{I_x} & & \text{or} &  \sigma_y(z) = \frac{M_x}{I_x}\,z \end{aligned}$$

The last part is the calculation of $I_x$. The sum of the torques due to the stress distribution *about the* **x***-axis* at the origin is evaluated by slicing the cross section at each height $z$.

$$ M_x = \int z\, \sigma_y {\rm d}A = \int K z^2 {\rm d}A = K \, \int z^2 {\rm d}A $$

therefore $$ \boxed{ I_x = \int z^2 {\rm d}A }$$

Note also, the the bending happens in the *yz* plane and there it is considered to be along the *x* axis (think of it as a rotation). So the label $I_x$ is appropriate.

### One last thought

The term "moment of inertia" in your post (and the linked paper) is incorrect. Inertia *only* refers to resistance to rotational motion in dynamics. The proper term is "second area moment", which describes exactly what it is. Take the second moment of an infinitesimal area ${\rm d}A$ and sum it up $\rightarrow \int z^2 {\rm d}A$.

Comment: Great answer, but $K$ should depend on the Young modulus of the material...The term "moment of inertia" is probably wrongly chosen, especially  for static problems, but it is widely used!

Comment: @user8736288 - The slope $K$ does not depend on modulus of _elasticity_. Young's modulus is used when calculating deflections and in this case we only consider the stress distribution. The slope depends solely on the shape and the applied moment.

Comment: @user8736288 - You mean moment of inertia is widely misused.

Comment: Sorry, you're completely right about $K$! Good luck on changing "moment of inertia"."moment of area"  is hardly any better, I agree "second moment of area" is the correct one. Minor point -  is there a particular convention as to why the represented stress seem to counteract $M_{x}$?  I woud read $M_{x}= -z\sigma_{y}/I_{x}$ from your diagram.

Comment: @user8736288 if stress was a vector we would use a cross product, bit because it is a tensor we are stuck with index notation. The moment is $$ {\rm d} M_x = (y \sigma_z - z \sigma_y) {\rm d}A $$ but we only have stress in one direction.  The stress formula used in engineering is $$ \sigma_y(z) = \frac{z\,M_x}{I_x}$$ or $$ \boxed{ M_x = I_x \; \frac{ \sigma_y}{z}} $$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the length of your beam is along the $x$-axis and the deflection towards $z$-axis, what counts for the bending moment in pure bending of beams is the **area moment of inertia** of the cross-section of your beam, that is the area in the $yz$-plane according to my assumption above. If your cross-section is rectangular with width $b$ and height $h$ you find the expression you've indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Your beam defletcts in the  $z$ direction, but the sections of your beam rotates around the $x$ axis, hence the name given.